Distributing row sums of an integer matrix to be close to Poisson with constraints on column totals and non-zero counts
I have a situation where I want to build an $M\times N$ matrix called $H$ representing $M$ objects with a possible $N$ different modifiers all of which can be applied in positive integer quantities. I know that each modifier has a column total specified, i.e. $\sum^{i\in 1:M} H_{i,j} = T_j, j\in 1:N$. There is also a binary matrix $D_{i,j} \in \{1,0\}$ signifying objects which are affected by the $j$th modifier, i.e. we know a number $S_j$ of entries of $H$ that will be non-zero. Necessarily, we establish that $S_j \leq T_j \forall j\in 1:N$ as there must be at least one modifier quantity per object indicated by $D$, and the rest of the values of that column must be zero.
I want the row sums of this matrix to be roughly Poisson distributed, but with these constraints I feel it is impossible to guarantee this is achievable. So alternatively, I would like an efficient algorithm to get as close as possible in assigning modifiers such that there is a roughly exponential decay on the quantity of total modifiers applied from a row sums perspective.
I believe without the $D$ matrix part restricting exactly how many objects have each modifier it should be quite easy to achieve this using a multinomial distribution on each column (with an optional Dirichlet prior to be able to concentrate / make uniform the distribution). Does anyone have any ideas for achieving this easily?

I did a small MathJax correction, changing $M$ x $N$ to $M\times N.$ That is standard usage.
